# Python: Check for new files and wait until they have finished transferring

Tags: python, video, filesystems, windows-server-2008

I have a script to scan a directory to see when new files are added, and then process their contents. They're video files, so they're often very large, and they're being transferred over a network and often take a long time to transfer. So I need to make sure they have finished copying before going on.

At the moment, once I've found a new file in the directory I'm using os.path.mtime to check the modification date, and comparing that to the last time the file was scanned, to see if it is still being modified. The theory being that if it's no longer being modified then it should have finshed transferring.

```
if getmtime(path.join(self.rootFolder, thefile)) < self.lastchecktime: newfiles.append[thefile]
```

but that doesn't seem to work - the script gets triggered too early and the processing fails because the file is not fully loaded. Could it be that there is not enough of a pause between scans that the mtime stays the same…? I give it 10 seconds between scans - that should be enough, surely.

Is there an easy / more pythonic way of doing this? The files are on a windows server running on a VM.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any control over the adding of the files? If so, you could create an empty file with a name like `videoname-complete` once a video has finished uploading, and watch for those files.

Comment: Although not "pure" and not the best possible solution, this is often used in practice (based on my experience with enterprise integration systems).  It's kind of clunky, but does work. +1

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't your check be "is my modified time greater than last checked?".

```
if os.path.getmtime(path) > self.lastAccessedTime: 
    # do something as modified time is greater than last time I checked
    pass
```

I'm not a windows guy, but I'm sure there will be some equivalent library to inotify for windows. It is a really nice way to listen for file or directory changes on file system level. I'm leaving some sample code which works on linux with pyinotify, would be helpful for someone on linux.

```
class PTmp(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):
        print "Changed: %s " % os.path.join(event.path, event.name)


wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
mask = pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, PTmp())
wdd = wm.add_watch(FILE_LOCATION, mask, rec=True)

while True:
    try:
        notifier.process_events()
        if notifier.check_events():
            notifier.read_events()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        notifier.stop()
        break
```

Comment: no, if the modify time is greater than the last time I checked then something has happened to the file in the meantime and it could still be loading. Finding new files works, it's just finding new files that have finished changing that's the problem. I've updated the question

Comment: Sorry are you trying to check if the file has finished uploading?

Comment: yes, hence the "wait until they have finished transferring" in the title.

Comment: I think this needs some sort of support from OS to make it reliable. In linux there are few handy utilities you can play with, like lsof to check if the file is open by another process. So you can check the modified time along with checking if file is still open perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the inotify suggestion. I think I need to push harder to get a linux / os X server for this.